# Printing float values using only syscalls in C

Tags: c, floating-point, double, system-calls

I am trying to write a C program to print the filesizes in human readable format (i.e, in KB, MB, GB, etc). The input is the filesize in bytes. The catch is that this is to be done using only system calls and NO library calls.

I have already written a function that converts a positive integer into a string and then prints it using write() system call. I am clueless as to how to print decimal values using write() as the filesize after conversion(in KB or MB or GB) could be decimals.(For Ex: 4.0K, 5.6G etc).

Also, is it possible to limit precision to some fixed length (say 2 decimal places) ??

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with here?  Writing something that prints `double` values accurately is quite hard, but you don't need to do that.  Your last couple paragraphs make me think you haven't even tried anything here.

Answer (score 2):

For a lot of cases, you can convert your floats the same way you do with integers. First convert the integer part by casting your float to int and converting that to string. Then append the decimal point, subtract the integer from your original float, multiply by your required precision and do the same (with leading zeros if required).

Conceptually you could do something like that:

```
int integerPart = myFloat;
int decimalPart = (myFloat - integerPart) * 1000; // for three decimal places
char* stringRep = intToStringNoLeadingZeros(integerPart);
appendChar(stringRep, '.');
appendIntToStringWithLeadingZeros(stringRep, decimalPart);
```

This **does not work** with floats that are larger than the largest possible integer and it **will lose precision** if you need lots of decimal places. But for the common case this is a quick way to do it. You would have to write code that interpretes the floating point format directly if you want it to work for alle cases, but I imagine that to be a lot more work.

Comment: Oh yeah, and you will need to handle negative numbers separately. If myFloat is negative, multiply it by -1 and prepend the string with '-'.

Comment: It can also print out the wrong number for certain carefully-crafted inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is your solution:

```
#include <unistd.h>

void printInt(int n) {
  char c;

  if (!n)
    return ;
  printInt(n/10);
  c = n % 10 + '0';
  write(1, &c, 1);
}

void    _printInt(int n) {
  if (!n)
    write(1, "0", 1);
  else
    printInt(n);
}

void    _printD(double n, int K) {
  _printInt((int)n);
  n -= (int)n;
  if (!n && !K)
    return ;
  write(1, ".", 1);
  while ((!n && K) || K) {
    _printInt((int)(n*10));
    n=n*10-((int)(n*10));
    K--;
  }
}

int main() {
  _printD(10.543, 2);
  return 0;
}
```

if you need some advice just say!

Answer (score 0):

```
void printNum(unsigned n){
    char nums[4];
    int i;
    if(n == 0)
        write(1, "0", 1);
    for(i=4; n ;){
        nums[--i] = '0' + n % 10;
        n /= 10;
    }
    write(1, &nums[i], 4 - i);
}

void printStr(const char *s){
    while(*s)
        write(1, s++, 1);
}

void printSizeWithUnit(unsigned long long n){
    static char *unit[] = { "B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB", "PB", "EB" };
    unsigned long long v = n;
    int u_no = 0;
    while(n >= 1024){
        v = (n * 10+512) / 1024;
        n /= 1024;
        ++u_no;
    }
    if(v>=1000){
        v = (n * 10+512) / 1024;
        ++u_no;
    }
    if(u_no==0){
        printNum((unsigned)v);
        printStr(unit[u_no]);
        printStr("\n");
    } else {
        printNum((unsigned)v/10);
        printStr(".");
        printNum((unsigned)v%10);
        printStr(unit[u_no]);
        printStr("\n");
    }
}

int main(void){
    printSizeWithUnit(777ULL);
    printSizeWithUnit((unsigned long long)(5.56*1024*1024));
    printSizeWithUnit(1024*777ULL);
    printSizeWithUnit(1024*1024*777ULL);
    return 0;
}
```